# Create tiles from Mars HiRISE images

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, tile-server, mars

I have a problem with creating tiles from from Mars HiRISE images using gdal/gda2tiles. Can't find info regarding this topic, so, maybe someone already faced that issue?

Image looks like this

[image]

Final goal is to show this tiles on the top of CesiumJS, but for now Leaflet/OL/etc map would be also fine.

Input source file has following parameters:

[image]

What worries me a bit here is the fact, that

[image]

Datum is unknown. Maybe this is the source of all my problems with further processing, but this is just my guess.

QGIS show following SRS:

[image]

For tiles generation I use gda2tiles utility.

If I try to run gdal2tiles directly from Python like this

```
minZoomLevel = 8
maxZoomLevel = 12
options = {'zoom': (minZoomLevel, maxZoomLevel)}
gdal2tiles.generate_tiles(sourceImagePath, outputTilesFolder, **options)
```

I got following output:

[image]

So, for sure something is wrong.

I tried different resampling values, tried to provide also source Spatial reference, but that didn't help.

After googling I also tried before calling gdal2tiles to wrap original image and only then call gdal2tiles.
So, I tried

```
gdalwarp -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ot Int16 -r cubic /MarsData/esp_057760_2025_red.jp2 /MarsData/warped.tif
```

and then call gda2tiles for warped.tif, but that didn't help.

I also tried to provide input file SRS for wrapping (took it from QGIS)

```
gdalwarp -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -s_srs '+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=20 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3393833.2607584 +b=3393833.2607584 +units=m +no_defs' -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ot Int16 -r cubic /MarsData/esp_057760_2025_red.jp2 /MarsData/warped.tif
```

But this also didn't help. I still see the same output tiles.

Can someone point me where is my problem and how to solve it?